# Ng-content not parsed for downgraded angular 2 component

Tags: typescript, angular

My goal is to create an universal tab component for Angular2 as shown below:

```
<tabs>
   <tab tabTitle="Tab 1">This is tab 1 content</tab>
   <tab tabTitle="Tab 2">This is tab 2 content</tab>
</tabs>
```

However when I implement this component based on this [excellent example](http://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/) I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'active' of undefined
```

The reason for this is probably `@ContentChildren(Tab) tabs: QueryList<Tab>;` is unable to parse the `<tab>` tags defined between the `<tabs>` tag. This leaves `tabs` without any children and therefore doesn't have any tabs to set to active.

A live example is available on [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Uswvn9ecaWPr7fZDkcG?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<tabscontainer></tabscontainer>
```

**TabsContainer.ts**

```
import {Tabs} from './Tabs';
import {Tab} from './Tab';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabscontainer',
  template: `
    <tabs>
      <tab tabTitle="Tab 1">This is tab 1 content</tab>
      <tab tabTitle="Tab 2">This is tab 2 content</tab>
    </tabs>
  `,
  directives: [Tabs, Tab]
})
export class TabsContainer {
  constructor() { }
}
```

**Tab.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `
    <div [hidden]="!active">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})

@Injectable()
export class Tab {
  @Input('tabTitle') title: string;
  @Input() active = false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `Upgrade`?

Comment: That's because we have a legacy application that we are migrating to angular 2. Tabs would be the first thing to switch versions.

Comment: I see. I don't know about upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
  selectTab(tab: Tab) {
    // deactivate all tabs
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);

    // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
    tab.active = true;
  }
```

to

```
  selectTab(tab: Tab) {
    // deactivate all tabs
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);

    // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
    if(tab) {
      tab.active = true;
    }
  }
```

fixes the error message.
I don't know yet why `selectTab(...)` is called with tabs and then again without any tabs - this is when `tab.active` trhows because `tab` is `null`.

You have

```
<tabs>
  <tab>Tab 1</tab>
  <tab>Tab 2</tab>
</tabs>
```

in your `index.html`. `<ng-content>` isn't supported on the root component. You should wrap your entire application in an application component and put the tab in there.